# How to SQL Tuning?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I would like to ask for some help regarding SQL tuning. I need to optimize an existing production SQL query to run efficiently with low cache memory use.

I tried to insert the "from" part in a DB table and source from there but the job where this query is incorporated makes it run significantly slower.

This is the prechange:

```
FROM (  SELECT /*+ FULL(A) FULL(B) PARALLEL(A,10) PARALLEL(B,10) */
           A.*, B.CCNA, B.CCNA_NAME
        FROM TMP2 A, CNA B
        WHERE A.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = B.DOCUMENT_NUMBER(+)
     ) A,

   (SELECT /*+ FULL(A) FULL(B) PARALLEL(A,10) PARALLEL(B,10) */
           A.*, B.STATE
            FROM    (
                    SELECT /*+ FULL(A) FULL(B) PARALLEL(A,10) PARALLEL(B,10) */
                        A.*, B.USOC
                    FROM TMP1 A, COSS B
                    WHERE A.SERV_ITEM_ID = B.SERV_ITEM_ID(+)
                    ) A,
    STATE B
         WHERE A.SERV_ITEM_ID = B.SERV_ITEM_ID(+)) B
 WHERE A.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = B.DOCUMENT_NUMBER(+)
```

This is the postchange:

```
FROM   TMP_TMP2 A,
        TMP_TMP1_B B 
WHERE A.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = B.DOCUMENT_NUMBER(+);
```

The "from" part is the same, I just assigned the postchange into tables.
Please see the full code here:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KAoupkleVySjYqX_sVDdWMETfc8JlOXR

Comment: I'd get rid of all the hints if I were you, or at least the `full` hints, for a start.

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax. It's been 27 years since SQL-92 already. It makes queries much easier to read and to debug.

Comment: 'modern' join syntax won't make it any faster though

Comment: @thatjeffsmith it won't, but it will improve readability and therefore maintainability. Embrace the ANSI-style joins already! *{;-)

Comment: @Boneist I thought opinions were frowned upon here ;) People spend more time critiquing join syntax than actually trying to answer the question. I find that very curious.

Comment: Losing the hints and gathering stats has made me a tuning hero many times. Also formatting code can help you understand the structure which can lead to rewriting.